# Hazelcast IMap.entrySet() does not return all entries

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I'm working on a simple example of a distributed IMap persisted in MySQL database through MapStore implementation.
I manually entered 6 entries in the DB table and I want to read them using the Hazelcast's IMap.

If I read entries like this:

```
IMap<Long, Person> personMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("personMap");
personMap.get(1L));
personMap.get(2L));
personMap.get(3L));
personMap.get(4L));
personMap.get(5L));
personMap.get(6L));
```

everything works fine. When I debug the DB access I see that on first get() Hazelcast first pre-loads keys 4,3,5,6 and then key 1. On second get() it loads key 2. On subsequent 4 get() lines, keys are already present in the personMap, so there is no DB access. So far so good.

Now, when I replace snippet with:

```
IMap<Long, Person> personMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("personMap");
for(Map.Entry<Long, Person>entry : personMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(personMap.get(entry.getKey())); 
}
```

On loop initialization, on entrySet() call, Hazelcast loads only keys 3,4,5 and 6. This loop thus does not print keys 1 and 2, only keys 3,4,5 and 6.

Any ideas why is that so? It's Hazelcast 3.6

Note: Of course, when I call entrySet() after the keys 1 through 6 are already explicitly loaded, for example by combining both snippets in one "run", then entrySet() sees all the keys. Problem happens only if entrySet() is the first actual access to the personMap.

**Update:** I also tried explicit load prior to calling entrySet():

```
IMap<Long, Person> personMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("personMap");
personMap.loadAll(true);
```

Result is the same - only keys 3 through 6 are loaded. My cluster consists of only one node.

Comment: which version of Hazelcast do you use ?

Comment: Tried to reproduce [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9872d74fb1be074ee8ee) , but no luck. Is it possible to share a reproducer test-code?

Comment: stuhpa From what I see in your question, it is supposed to work the way you expect it, therefore it must be a bug. Can you please open a github issue and provide some code to reproduce your issue? As @amrck pointed out we're not able to reproduce it so we really appreciate any help / hint / code :)